# Does FileMaker Pro ExecuteSQL support subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql, filemaker

I was just wondering whether the FileMaker Pro command "ExecuteSQL()" supports subqueries within the SQL Query?

This is the query that I have got at the moment:

```
"SELECT Google_Calendar  FROM SCHEDULE WHERE Group_ID = ( SELECT Group_ID FROM SCHEDULE WHERE Schedule_ID = "& EscapeSQL( GSPNo( 1 ) ) &" )"
```

I keep getting an error and I know all of the fields are correct and the actual query would work in something like PHPMyAdmin.

So, does anyone know whether this would work or is there some limitations on the queries?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're referring to the script step "Execute SQL", then it can only work with external data sources. It cannot run SQL queries against FileMaker tables. If you're referring to the internal SQL API which is available through some plug-ins (and via FileMaker ODBC/JDBC driver), then yes, this API does support subqueries.

Comment: Just FYI, you can execute SQL to perform queries to filemaker tables. I was doing it yesterday. It does not need to be an external source for the ExecuteSQL function to work.

Answer (score 0):

More recent versions of Filemaker (certainly 13+) will indeed let you do this now. Statements are limited to SELECT, but you can use subqueries, according to the [docs](https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/docs/13/en/fm13_sql_reference.pdf).